# Skyrim Mods: Making sense of the REFR Change Form

Tags: skyrim-modding

I'm trying to parse a Skyrim SE save file, in order to determine where specific items, say Alchemy or Smithing ressources, are located in my containers in the world.

I have been able to parse REFR Changed Form most of the times:

```
ChangedForm.formId = 00002A68
ChangedForm.changeFlags = 134217760
ChangedForm.DataLengthSize = uint8
ChangedForm.TypeOfForm = REFR
ChangedForm.version = 78
ChangedForm.length1 = 85
ChangedForm.length2 = 0
ChangedForm.data = System.Byte[]
Inventory.Inventory Count = 5
InventoryItem.Inventory Item = 1 00006E1C
InventoryItem.Inventory Item = 1 00006E18
InventoryItem.Inventory Item = 4 00065C9F
InventoryItem.Inventory Item = 2 000EBA03
InventoryItem.Inventory Item = 3 00034CDF
```

What I don't know is how to determine what container this inventory is for, and where it is, for example: Chest in Breezehome.

Can someone help me find the correct path to the information I need?

Thanks